# how to make in app purchase for app with multiple target iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an app with two different targets: free and paid. I have already coded everything and it works but I'm unsure how to release the app. I'm wondering whether I should just release those two apps or is there any way for me to use in-app purchase for an app with multiple targets?

Like, a user purchases an app upgrade in the free app and then they automatically get the paid version of the app after making that purchase, is that possible? I looked around for in-app purchase guides, but none of them seem to be working with multiple app targets.

Comment: by **GET** do you mean they download the premium version or **GET ACCESS TO** premium features?

Comment: ideally get access to premium features, but since I ended up making two separate targets of the same app (one target is paid and one is free) it's a bit complicated?

Comment: Have you looked into the `Freemium` business model? Apple includes how you can get it sorted [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/freemium-business-model/)

Answer (score 1):

You can either release a free app and a paid-up-front app or merge both targets into one app and allow the user to unlock the premium features via an in-app purchase (freemium, as already mentioned by @Visal).

I would suggest the latter: Short-term it is more work for you because you have to merge both targets. But long-term, it has a lot of advantages:

- you have to maintain only one app
- the reviews aren't spread over two apps
- it is the more convenient solution for your users since they do not have to download the same app again when they want to get the premium features.